# Unable to install the randomForest package

Tags: r, package, random-forest

I am trying to install the randomForest package in RStudio and have not been able to do so successfully.

I tried the following code and got the error message further down below. I also tried to use the "Install Packages" function under "Tools" and could not find the randomForest package in CRAN. I can only see packages of "randomForestExplainer" "RandomForestsGLS" and "randomForestSRC"

install.packages("randomForest")

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘randomForest’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

I would appreciate it if someone could kindly advise what went wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current release of `randomForest` requires R version 4.1.0 or newer.  You are using R 3.6.1, which is three years old.

The best thing for you to do is to update to the current R release, but if that is impossible for some reason, then you'll need to try to find an older version of `randomForest` and install that.  This is likely to waste a **lot** of time, because it may depend on other old packages, etc.  You can see what's available on this page:  https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/, but you'll have to download to find which versions of R are compatible.